# CTE with Insert Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have previously been helped out with this code but I am now wanting to add the result set in to a separate table variable **@check** but can't work out where to add the Insert statements due to the **Union** statements?

```
 DECLARE @customer_dist TABLE
    (
        [id] [INT] NOT NULL ,
        [First_Name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
        [Last_Name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
        [DoB] [DATE] NULL ,
        [post_code] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
        [mobile] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
        [Email] [VARCHAR](100) NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @customer_dist ( id ,
                             First_Name ,
                             Last_Name ,
                             DoB ,
                             post_code ,
                             mobile ,
                             Email )

select id, first_name, last_name, dob, post_code, mobile, email from checky where NID = 148575

 DECLARE @check TABLE
    (
        [id] [INT] NOT NULL ,
        [NID] [INT] NOT NULL 
    )



;with PairedRows as ( 
  select CDL.id as NId, CDR.id as Id
    from @customer_dist as CDL inner join
      @customer_dist as CDR on CDR.Id > CDL.Id and 
        CDR.First_Name = CDL.First_Name and CDR.Last_Name = CDL.Last_Name and CDR.DoB = CDL.DoB and 
        ( CDR.post_code = CDL.post_code or CDR.mobile = CDL.mobile or CDR.Email = CDL.Email ) 
    where not exists (
      select 42 from @customer_dist as NE where NE.ID < CDL.Id and 
        NE.First_Name = CDL.First_Name and NE.Last_Name = CDL.Last_Name and NE.DoB = CDL.DoB and
        ( NE.post_code = CDL.post_code or NE.mobile = CDL.mobile or NE.Email = CDL.Email ) ) )
  select NId, Id 
    from PairedRows
  union all
  select Min( NId ) as NID, Min( NId ) as Id 
    from PairedRows
    group by NId
  union all
  select id, id 
    from @customer_dist as CD
    where not exists ( select 42 from PairedRows as PR where PR.NId = CD.id or PR.Id = CD.id )
  order by NID, Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
  bah AS
(
  stuff
)
INSERT INTO
  table
SELECT foo FROM bah
UNION ALL
SELECT foo FROM bah
UNION ALL
SELECT foo FROM bah
```

Comment: I have tired adding it after each one of my Union statements but I get the error "Invalid object name 'PairedRows'" sorry previous type but error is still the same.

Comment: First, it's got an `s` on the end in your code *(`PairedRows`, not `PairedRow`)*?  Second, you should only have `INSERT INTO table` ***once***, before any of the selects that you are UNIONing.  Finally, if you get an error, show us the code that gives the error.

Comment: I mean that I have tried adding the insert statement at each point within the union and not all at the same time.  And the code that is failing is listed above, it's failing on the insert from the CTE in to a table.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out where to add it, thanks for the pointer

```
;with PairedRows as ( 

  select CDL.id as NId, CDR.id as Id
    from @customer_dist as CDL inner join
      @customer_dist as CDR on CDR.Id > CDL.Id and 
        CDR.First_Name = CDL.First_Name and CDR.Last_Name = CDL.Last_Name and CDR.DoB = CDL.DoB and 
        ( CDR.post_code = CDL.post_code or CDR.mobile = CDL.mobile or CDR.Email = CDL.Email ) 
    where not exists (
      select 42 from @customer_dist as NE where NE.ID < CDL.Id and 
        NE.First_Name = CDL.First_Name and NE.Last_Name = CDL.Last_Name and NE.DoB = CDL.DoB and
        ( NE.post_code = CDL.post_code or NE.mobile = CDL.mobile or NE.Email = CDL.Email ) ) )
insert into @check
  select NId, Id 
    from PairedRows
union all
  select Min( NId ) as NID, Min( NId ) as Id 
    from PairedRows
    group by NId
union all
  select id, id 
    from @customer_dist as CD
    where not exists ( select 42 from PairedRows as PR where PR.NId = CD.id or PR.Id = CD.id )
order by NID, Id
```

Comment: So, exactly where I said to put it?

Comment: Yes but I think I must of had a typo when I initially tested, I have marked your answer as the correct answer.